# What should be connected to pins 3 and 4 of this 1/4 inch mono jack?

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, mixer

What should be connected to pins 3 and 4 of this 1/4 inch mono jack?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> *what should be the connect for the 1/4 mono jack for pin 4 and 3*

Please note what is written below: -

[image]

Sometimes pin 4 is connected to ground in other more sensitive applications.

Sometimes pin 3 is used to disconnect a battery supply but, not on your application.

Answer (score 0):

Those are "normalizing switches" that close when there is nothing plugged in.  You normally don't want unconnected metal parts right next to your signal, so when unused it would be typical to connect 3 to 1 and 2 to 4.

Now this is an audio input amplifying the current into a 1k resistance by 100kOhm .  It's probably not overly sensitive to hum, but when the input is left open, you'll get the thermal noise from the 100kOhm feedback resistor amplified, and connecting the normalising contact 4 to GND will cut the idle noise with an unplugged input down significantly.

In a nutshell: I'd connect both 3 and 4 to GND.  Downside: if the 2–4 switch does not open reliably (because the inserted plug has substandard diameter or the socket is worn out or low-quality from the get-go), your signal may get shorted or intermittent.

Answer (score 0):

Pin 3 is unimportant.

Connect pin 4 to ground. This will ensure that when the nothing is plugged in, the amplifier input is grounded, and the amplifier will stay "silent".